# Proving that $A_{[ab,c]}$ is a Tensor.

Tags: tensors

Let $A_{ab}$ be an antisymmetric vector field, show that $A_{[ab,c]}$ is a tensor.

I tried tackling the problem by showing that $A_{[ab,c]}$= $\frac{1}{3}(A[ab,c]+A[bc,a]+A[ca,b])$.

But from here I can’t seem to figure out how to prove that the previous expression is a tensor since the partial derivatives are not tensors, so maybe someone could direct me the in right way of how to continue from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The straight-forward way to show that something is a tensor is to transform it to a different coordinate system and see how the components change. It takes some work, but it gets the job done basically all the time. Partial derivatives might not be tensors, but adding six of them together might just cancel the non-tensor-stuff away.

Comment: @Arthur how do you go about transforming a partial derivative? I am sorry if this questions seems trivial but I am new to tensors.

Comment: You say that you know that partial derivatives are not tensors. How do you know that if you haven't seen how to transform one and observed that it does not conform to the tensor rules? And this problem isn't trivial, but "the in right way of how to continue from here", at least knowing what you ought to try first, is almost trivial: Transform it and see what happens.